# How to avoid elements in split function to be saved in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I'm trying to use split() method in javascript and the elements that are split are saved as an array which I don't want to be done.

I want  the elements to be saved as values in an object.

```
var string = "as1234,as5678,as6789";
var result = {}
result.values = string.split(',');
```

Output that I'm getting is below :

```
  result{
values : ["as1234","as5678","as6789"]
}
```

Output that I want is :

```
result{
values : "as1234","as5678","as6789"
}
```

Comment: ...and what keys would be used to store them?

Comment: What do you expect the `result` object to be?

Comment: Result object should be like this result{values: "as1234","as4567","as6789"}

Comment: you get already the wanted result, but in an array.

Comment: @Harish that is incorrect format

Comment: `result` will be `{values: ["as1234","as4567","as6789"]}`

Comment: This is how I got the result : result{values:["as1234","as4567","as6789"]} which i dont want

Comment: _What do you want_

Comment: split returns an array, What you want is not valid syntax so not sure what you want.

Comment: I guess you do not understand how the comma operator works. If you were to type that code into your console and run it, it would say: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," What you want is NOT valid... What is your problem with the array. The array is how you get each item separately...

Comment: The "output that I want" here is a plain syntax error. Why do you want that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want a string with the values padded by quote, you could split the string and stringify every element of the array and join it together to a string.

```js
var string = "as1234,as5678,as6789",
    result = {};

result.values = string.split(',').map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

---

Or if the pattern is consistent, you can use a regex to get the groups and parse string accordingly.

```js
var string = "as1234,as5678,as6789",
    result = {};

result.values = string.replace(/([a-z0-9]+)/g,"\"$1\"")
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thats why I added in your answer. But thought `string.replace` would be better than `split`+`map`+`join` and so made your answer as a consolidated answer.